# Import error, can't find file: highcharts/histogram-bellcurve

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am trying to implement the official version of the highchart (highcharts-angular) in a angular application and created a stackblitz example of it . Currently I am getting error

```
Import error, can't find file:
highcharts/histogram-bellcurve
```

Stackblitz example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k85q94

Could somebody tell me what I am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import it as

```
const hb = require('highcharts/modules/histogram-bellcurve');
```

Forked [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h7c3ms?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

Answer (score 0):

The bell curve requires an expecific jar named *histogram-bellcurve*
Did you already import the histogram-bellcurve.js ?

This file .js can be found at following link: 
[histogram-bellcurve.js](https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/histogram-bellcurve.js), download this file and import it to your project.

For more information about Highcharts, visit the Highchart documentation:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/